# How to define index for an embeddable class in Hibernate 5.2.3?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, indexing

I have an embeddable class defined as;

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Observation{

     @Column(name = "created")
      private LocalDateTime created;

     @Column(name="code")
      private string code
      ---

    }
```

And my entity class is;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mete_observation", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"),
public class MeterObservation{

 @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "created", column = @Column(name = "ob_created")) })
    private Observation raw = null; 
}
```

I want to create indexes observation/created field and observation/code.

What is the best way to create indexes? Should I define them in the Embeddable class? Or Can i define that from the Entity Class? and How should I define? Any example please.

Comment: Where's the problem with defining them in the `@Table` annotation of `MeterObservation`

Comment: @NeilStockton at the MeterObservation entity I would like to define. If I define indexes like Observation.code, It gives issue. (Says code is not public variable) I could not find the reference .

Comment: In which case raise a bug on your JPA provider, since "code" is certainly a column in that table (when you create the schema using the JPA provider does it create a column called 'code'?).

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes it creates column.

Comment: So raise a bug on Hibernate.

Comment: @Ratha finally where you have created indexes in Embeddable or Entity class. I am facing similar problem when I declare index on my embeddable class. Using table annotation. They never gets created on table.

Answer (score 0):

Adding indices to embedded objects can be a little bit tricky. The exact column name is necessary in order to make it work.
As the `created` column name is overwritten with `AttributeOverrides` the column for the index is not called `created` but `ob_created`.

With no additional configuration the indices look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "mete_observation",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"),
    indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "ob_created", name = "idx_created"), // not 'created' but 'ob_created' as it is overwritten
        @Index(columnList = "code", name = "idx_code"),
    }
)
public class MeterObservation{
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "created", column = @Column(name = "ob_created")) })
    private Observation raw = null; 
}
```

(Tested with JPA 2.2.3 and Hibernate 5.4.15.)

---

Additional complexity comes into play if the implicit-strategy for the naming has been set to `ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl`. That changes the column names as well.

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "mete_observation",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"),
    indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "ob_created", name = "idx_created"), // the AttributeOverride 'ob_created' beats the naming strategy
        @Index(columnList = "raw_code", name = "idx_code"), // adding 'raw_' for the naming strategy
    }
)
public class MeterObservation{
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "created", column = @Column(name = "ob_created")) })
    private Observation raw = null; 
}
```

Comment: Can we create indexes on Embeddable class.